# Undefined value from event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, salesforcedx, lightning-events

I am trying to get the value of (firstName, lastName, emailAddress, mobile) from the parent component and use it in my child component but when I set it into params and logged the values, I always got an undefined result. Please advice and thank you in advance. :)

[image]

**Event.evt**

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="lastName" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="email" type="Map" />
    <aura:attribute name="mobile" type="Map" />
</aura:event>
```

**parent_component.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="lastName" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="email" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="mobile" type="String" default=""/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="registerDetailsEvent" type="c:Event" />

                <c:FormInput
                    aura:id="firstName"
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    value="{!v.firstName}"
                    label="{!$Label.c.firstName}"
                    onkeyup="{!c.onChange}" />

                <c:FormInput
                    aura:id="lastName"
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    value="{!v.lastName}"
                    label="{!$Label.c.lastName}"
                    onkeyup="{!c.onChange}" />

                <c:FormInput
                    aura:id="email"
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    value="{!v.email}"
                    label="{!$Label.c.email}"
                    onkeyup="{!c.onChange}" />

                <c:FormInput
                    aura:id="mobile"
                    type="text"
                    name="mobile"
                    value="{!v.mobile}"
                    maxlength="15"
                    label="{!$Label.c.mobile}"
                    onkeyup="{!c.onChange}" />

</aura:component>
```

**parent_component.js**

```
onChange : function (component, event, helper){
var registerDetailsEvent = component.getEvent("registerDetailsEvent");
    registerDetailsEvent.setParams({
    "firstName" : component.get("v.firstName"),
    "lastName" : component.get("v.lastName"),
    "email" : component.get("v.email"),
    "mobile" : component.get("v.mobile")
});
    registerDetailsEvent.fire();
}
```

**child_component.cmp**

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:handler name="registerDetailsEvent" event="c:Event" action= 
    {!c.registerDetailsEvent}"/>

</aura:component>
```

**child_component.js**

```
registerDetailsEvent: function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('Shoot');                                 
    console.log("firstName:", event.getParam("firstName"));
    console.log("lastName: ", event.getParam("lastName"));
    console.log("email: ", event.getParam("email"));
    console.log("mobileNumber: ", event.getParam("mobile"));
}
```

Comment: why are you using 4 map attributes? seems counter productive imo

Comment: additionally, when are you firing your event? is component.get("v.attribute") returning something before you fire the event?

Comment: @glls yeah, It has values. I put the firing of the event on the onkeyup event in the input field. Please see changes in the code above. Thanks

Comment: @glls we are using customize components for the form inputs

Comment: yes, i noticed, but why? what do they do that standard input fields dont?

Answer (score 3):

Component events are “clones” of standard DOM events (mouse clicks, key press, and so on). Just like their DOM counterparts, they propagate up in the component hierarchy via a bubbling mechanism and can be stopped en route to the application root component.
[image]

you can achieve it using aura methods .or try with the application events but not with components.
in your case you are trying to create a component event and do parent to child communication which is not possible.

Comment: How application events work and how to implement it? I tried $A.get("e.c:Event") but I got an error also.

Comment: check this https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using an `Application` event for this.

Reserve application events for communication between unconnected components or for when you need to communicate with multiple child components at once.

As @keepler said, use an `Aura` method for this. Example:

```
<aura:method name="registerDetails" action="{!c.doRegisterDetails}" > 
  <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="lastName" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="email" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="mobile" type="String" />
</aura:method>
```

Part of the controller method, `doRegisterDetails`:

```
doRegisterDetails : function(cmp, event) {
    var params = event.getParam('arguments');
    if (params) {
        var firstName = params.firstName;
        // etc
    }
}
```

And calling:

```
 component.find("mychildcomponent").registerDetails(firstName,lastName,email,mobile);
```

This assumes that the child component IS actually a child of the parent component.